# Exporting Mongoose connection to a different file

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, import

Current file/folder structure:

**Part 1 - Create a mongoose connection**

path: myApp/src/db/mongoose.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/task-manager-api", { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  console.log("connected to database");
});

module.exports = mongoose; //this is redundant without assigning to a variable
```

**Part 2 - Importing it in a file where I run express**
path: myapp/index.js

```
import express from "express";
import "./src/db/mongoose";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

Error:
Cannot find module "myApp/src/db/mongoose" imported from "myApp/index"

Here's what I have tried:

1. I tried to use const mongoose = require("mongoose") and then module.exports = mongoose to move the connection to the index.js file but still no luck
2. A tonne of google search to find if a separate mongoose connection file is maintained anywhere
3. I looked up how to use require module in ES6 but still no luck

```
// import { createRequire } from "module";
// const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Any help/advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Expected output:

1. Mongoose connection imported into index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at doing something along the lines of

- wrapping your mongoose connect up in an exported function
- Import the connect function in your index.js and call it

The code may end up looking like this (Not tested!):
mongoose.js:

```
export const connect = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/task-manager-api", {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });
};
```

index.js

```
import express from "express";
import {connect} from "<...relevant_path_here...>/mongoose";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connect();
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("listening on port 3000");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```

Comment: thank you very much! It makes so much sense now. I should have made and transferred an asynchronous function to later call connect from the index.js file.